# Who are these deities mentioned in the Shatapatha Brahmana?

Tags: vedic-gods, vedic-rituals, shatapatha-brahmana

**[Shatapatha Brahmana 2.3.2](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1249.htm#fr_771)** while talking about the Agnihotra fire-sacrifice mentions the following verses:

> 1. Verily, in him that exists, **these deities reside, to wit, Indra, king Yama, Nada the Naishadha (king), Anasnat Sâṅgamana, and Asat Pâmsava.**
> 2. Now Indra, in truth, is the same as the Âhavanîya; and king Yama is the same as the Gârhapatya; and Nada Naishadha is the same as the Anvâhâryapakana (Dakshina fire); and because day by day they take that (fire) to the south, therefore indeed they say that day by day **Nada Naishadha carries king Yama (further) south.**
> 3. And again what fire there is in the hall (sabhâ), that is the same as **Anasnat Sâṅgamana**: Anasvat (not eating) it is for the reason that people approach it before they eat. And that (place) where they throw the ashes they remove (from the fireplaces) is the same as **Asat Pâmsava**. And whosoever knows this, thus gains all those worlds, traverses all those worlds, thinking, 'In me those gods reside.'

**I want to know if there are more dtails in any other scriptures regarding - Nada the Naishadha (king), Anasnat Sâṅgamana, and Asat Pâmsava?**